# Compare symbols in pyqgis

Tags: python, pyqgis, symbology, comparison

I'm working with renderers and I want to compare symbols from two different renderers. Is there any way to do it in pyqgis/python?

Here is how I get symbols:

```
renderer = layer.rendererV2()
category = renderer.categories()[0]
symbol = category.symbol()
```

Maybe you know any other way to compare symbols in PyQGIS?